# Finding a lower bound

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

Given four positive integers $n,$ $m,$ $l$ and $k \geq 2.$ I want to find a lower bound for this expression $$|\sqrt[k]{n}+\sqrt[k]{m}-\sqrt[k]{l}|$$ in terms of these integers. Many thanks